Is subspace topology admissible?
We defined the compact open topology as the topology on $M(X,Y)$ generated by the sets $U^K = \{f:X\to Y \text{ such that } f(K) \subset U\}$, for $K\subset X$ compact and $U\subset Y$ open. We showed that this topology is contained in every admissible topology; i.e., in each topology such that the evaluation map is continuous.
I have two questions regarding it. We showed furthermore that if $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact, then the compact open topology is admissible. Does anyone have an example of $X,Y$ where one can see easily that this is not admissible?
Furthermore, I'm wondering if the subspace topology $M(X,Y) \subset Y^X$ (seen as the product topology) is admissible or not. I assume probably not, because this is (at least I understood it this way) exactly the point of introducing the compact open topology, but how can I see this?

Is $M(X,Y)$ the set of continuous functions $X\to Y$? Also in the second paragraph is the assumption on $X$ that it is Hausdorff and locally compact?

Too many typos.....

M(X,Y) are all continuos functions $X \to Y$. In the second paragraph this is the assumption (but there is also written if X is Hausdorff and locally compact right?)
